# A replacement for window.onbeforeunload in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, onbeforeunload

Currently the functionality in my asp.net project is as follows:

A user controls is opened in showmodaldialog. The user does some functionality. But as the showmodaldialog is an window, it has close(x) button. Upon clicking of this close(x) button I have written window.onbeforeunload function which displays a message to user as a warning. And asks him to click on either on OK or Cancel buttons which are default in confirmation box that is shown in window.onbeforeunload.

But now I want to replace this functionality with something better. I want to display my own custom dialog with custom buttons with their own custom functionality.

Basically I want to make sure that once user starts the functionality in the user control, he should finish it and if he clicks on close(x) button he is to be shown my new custom dialog and need to prevent him from closing showmodaldialog.

Can anyone please suggest something which I can use in my situation?

Thank you.

Comment: I believe that `window.onbeforeunload` is the only event that you can use to give people a warning. It's not in your power to just not let a user leave.

Comment: This is not possible using a web browser. You have no control over that dialog or the user leaving said window other than said dialog.

Comment: In that case how can I disable the close(x) button of showmodaldialog just the way some time windows does for some installations?

Comment: By using a desktop application window rather than a browser window. You could instead using an in-page dialog such as a jQuery UI dialog containing an iFrame, but that still doesn't stop them from pressing the back button or closing the overall window.

Comment: ok. But can I use something to replace this event or functionality for my desired functionality?

Comment: Short answer is no. Long answer is still no.

Comment: :D. Ok. I accept that. This is last question, can I atleast disable close(x) button or hide title bar of showmodaldialog?